# Compute normals in shader issue

Tags: matrix, glsl, shader, projection, lighting

I have the following vertex shader to [rotate normals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14196252/rotate-normals-in-shader). Before I implemented that, I passed also the rotation matrix of the mesh to calculate the normals. That time lighting was just fine.

```
#version 150

uniform mat4 projection;
uniform mat4 modelview;

in vec3 position;
in vec3 normal;
in vec2 texcoord;

out vec3 fposition;
out vec3 fnormal;
out vec2 ftexcoord;

void main()
{
    mat4 mvp = projection * modelview;

    fposition   = vec3(mvp * vec4(position, 1.0));
    fnormal     = normalize(mat3(transpose(inverse(modelview))) * normal);
    ftexcoord   = texcoord;
    gl_Position = mvp * vec4(position, 1.0);
}
```

But with this shader, the lighting computed in the fragment shader turns with the camera. I haven't changed the fragment shader, so the issue should be in the code above.

What am I doing wrong in computing the normals?

Comment: "*I haven't changed the fragment shader, so the issue should be in the code above.*" Alternatively, your fragment shader was *always* broken. Indeed, if your lighting worked *without* the above code, that suggests that your lighting never worked at all.

Comment: @NicolBolas. It did work by passing view, model and normal matrix separated where the normal matrix had no translation applied, instead of calculating the normal matrix in the shader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The steps you use to create the normal Matrix might be out of order.

Try:

```
fnormal = normalize(transpose(inverse(mat3(modelview))) * normal)
```

**Edit:**

Since you are inverting the mat4, the translation values (which get truncated when a mat4 is converted to a mat3) are probably affecting the calculation of the inverse matrix.